# Unexpected Behavior with DirectoryInfo.Name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directory

I'm experiencing something odd.

Whenever I attempt to create a [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) object in my code and pass it the root drive (`C:`), that object's Name property is set to "Debug", and the Parent is set to the `{bin}` folder.

I don't try to replicate Windows Explorer very often, so I don't know if this is something common or not.

I was getting this on my development PC at home, and now it is doing it here at work.

Does anyone else get this or is it just me?

[image: code window]

Comment: I won't say VS 2010 doesn't have bugs, but it's always a good idea to start with the assumption that the bug is in your own code (as the responders pointed out below).

Comment: I was hoping so. Do you have a better name for a title? I'm happy to fix it.

Comment: "Unexpected behavior" is always a great term. That way it leaves the door open to either "the behavior is wrong" or "my expectations are wrong." All bases are covered.

Comment: Give a +1 if the title works better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set the initial path to `"C:\\"` or `@"C:\"`, not `"C:"`.

The `DirectoryInfo` is just defaulting to the current directory, which is `bin\Debug`.